# Differentiating between cells that have the same information for match function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Lets say I have these 3 tables that show interest rates for various different things (e.g. Auto Loan, Mortage, Credit Cards). The "######"s are just showing that there are values in those cells that are used to calculate the numbers at the bottom (0.01, 0.03, etc.). Lets also say that the range in excel for these 3 Data Tables is **A1:I6**.

```
|              |   DataTable 1   |               |              |   DataTable 2   |               |              |   DataTable 3   |               |
|:------------:|:---------------:|:-------------:|:------------:|:---------------:|:-------------:|:------------:|:---------------:|:-------------:|
| Low,Interest | Medium,Interest | High,Interest | Low,Interest | Medium,Interest | High,Interest | Low,Interest | Medium,Interest | High,Interest |
|--------------|-----------------|---------------|--------------|-----------------|---------------|:-------------|-----------------|---------------|
|    #######   |     #######     |    #######    |    #######   |     #######     |    #######    |    #######   |     #######     |    #######    |
|    #######   |     #######     |    #######    |    #######   |     #######     |    #######    |    #######   |     #######     |    #######    |
|     0.01     |       0.03      |      0.05     |     0.02     |       0.04      |      0.06     |     0.10     |       0.20      |      0.30     |
```

I have a drop down list in **A8** that contains the values Data Table 1, Data Table 2, and Data Table 3.

Lets say I have another table (**Range is K1:M14**).

```
|   Month   | Balance | Medium Interest |
|:---------:|:-------:|:---------------:|
|  January  | $100.00 |        3%       |
|  February | $103.00 |        3%       |
|   March   | $106.09 |        3%       |
|   April   | $109.27 |        3%       |
|    May    | $112.55 |        3%       |
|    June   | $115.93 |        3%       |
|    July   | $119.41 |        3%       |
|   August  | $122.99 |        3%       |
| September | $126.68 |        3%       |
|  October  | $130.48 |        3%       |
|  November | $134.39 |        3%       |
|  December | $138.42 |        3%       |
```

**I wrote a formula that would determine how the 3% gets into the Medium Interest column.**

```
=INDEX($A$6:$I$6,MATCH($A$8,$A$1:$I$1,0),MATCH($M$2,$A$2:$I$2,0))
```

It works when I choose Data Table 1 in the drop down list. It correctly places 3% which is the medium interest rate for Data Table 1 but when I choose either of the other 2 data tables, I get an invalid cell reference error. It would appear to me that the problem is that the formula cannot differentiate between the Low, Medium, and High columns for different tables.

This is essentially what I need to do in my real spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=INDEX($A$6:$I$6,MATCH($A$8,$A$1:$I$1,0)+MATCH($M$2,$A$2:$C$2,0)-1)
```

but note that matches must be exact, in particular the label for ColumnM and the corresponding indicators in ColumnsA:I.

The first MATCH provides the index number for the position of the value selected by drop-down but because the data is in blocks this only identifies which of three blocks. In addition to that it is necessary to identify which column with the block, achieved by matching the ColumnM label within the first block - to return 1 (Low), 2 (Medium) or 3 (High). Since each block starts with Low, adding 1 (for Low) and subtracting 1 provides the offset required from what the other MATCH will find anyway (if first column of whichever block) + 0 still first column (Low) of whichever block. 2 (Medium) -1 is 1 so the INDEX function takes one more than the index number returned by the first MATCH.

Comment: That works perfectly. So what did your changes do exactly? Why is there a `+` instead of `,` between the first and second match? Why do you have the `-1` at the end of the index function?